# C# parsing out data line by line by character location from txt file

Tags: c#, datatable, substring, dataadapter

Just looking to see what the best way to approach the following situation would be.

I am trying to make a small job that reads in a txt file which has a thousand or so lines;

Each line is about 40 characters long (mostly numbers, some letter identifiers).

I have used

```
            DataTable txtCache = new DataTable();
        txtCache.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column1"));


        string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(FILEcheck.Properties.Settings.Default.filePath);

       foreach (string line in lines)
       {
           txtCache.Rows.Add(line);              
       }
```

However, what I really want to do is a bit confusing and hard to explain so i'll do my best. An example of line is below: 
5498494000584454684840}eD44448774V6468465      Z

In the beginning of that long string is a "84", and then a "58" a little bit later. I need to do a comparison on these two numbers. They could be anything, but only a few combinations are acceptable in the file. They will always be in the same spot and same amount of characters (so it will always be 2 numbers and always in the 4-5 location). So I want to have 3 columns. I want the full string in 1 column, and then the 2 individual smaller numbers in columns of themselves. I can then compare them later on, and if there is an issue, I can return the full string which caused the issue.

Is this possible? I am just not sure how to parse out a substring based on character location and then loading it into a datatable.

Any advice would be appreciated. Thank you,

Comment: Try using string.Substring(x,y) : try this link for details http://www.dotnetperls.com/substring

Comment: You used the word "substring" quite a few times in this post, and the answer is just that, `Substring`.

Answer (score 1):

You could create the columns for each of items you are looking to store (whole string, first number, second number), and then add a row for each of the lines in the input file. You could just use the substring method to parse out the two digit numbers and store them. To do your analysis, you could parse the numbers out from the strings, or whatever else you need to do.

lines[0].Substring(3,2) will give you "84" in your above example. If you want the int, you could use Int32.Parse(lines[0].Substring(3,2))

Substring reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx